# How to compare two fields from two arrays - Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, field

I have two different arrays (@first, @second, for exemple) and I wanna compare $first[2] to $second[4]. If there is a match, then I'm gonna print some things. I'm new on Perl, and I thought this was an easy task, but I cannot figure ir out...i've tried many different thing, but my resul only compared one register on the first array to the second array.

Comment: show what you tried and what happened and tell what you expected/wanted to happen

Comment: what kind of comparison should you perform?

Comment: You should always post the code that you tried.  Otherwise, most people won't help you.

Comment: Correction: You should always post the code that you tried. Otherwise, most people _won't be able to_ help you.

Answer (score 4):

Are the values strings or numbers?

- Compare strings with `eq`
- Compare numbers with `==`

In case of doubt, probably use `eq`:

```
print "String same\n" if ($first[2] eq $second[4]);
print "Number same\n" if ($first[2] == $second[4]);
```